# To provide fadeIn and FadeOut for images in div tag

Tags: jquery

I had used a SetInterval jquery function to add a slideshow of few images.The image sourse are stored inside an array and also the time interval of displaying of each image is also stored in an array.The code is working, But I want to add a fadeIn and FadeOut for each image with duration and opacity,How can it be done. The code used is

```
  //timearray- is array storing time for each image
  //imagearray- is array storing each image source
  //image_div-is div tag in which images are displayed
  // total 5 images -so used count inside setInterval

function imageshow() {
    var imgfade = setInterval(function () {
        $("#img_div").css("background", "url('" + imagearray[count] + "')");
        clearInterval(imgfade);
        if (count < 4) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        };
        imageshow()
    }, timearray[count]);
}

imageshow();
```

I need to use fadeIn and FadeOut for each image.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just call `$("#img_div").fadeOut()` before setting the css, and `$("#img_div").fadeIn()` after setting the css?

Comment: @Snixtor I tried it yes it works but need duration and opacity too

Comment: When you say duration *and* opacity, do you mean the transition needs to end at a value other than 100% or 0% opacity? If so, jQuery `animate` would be what you're after - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @Snixtor can we use fadeTo(duration,opacity) instead of fadeIn and fadeOut

Comment: I don't see why not. Looking at the code it uses `animate` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments clarifying the issue, it looks like `fadeTo` is the function you want. http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: You've marked user704808s response as the answer, which recommended `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`. I'd already suggested those functions, but you said you _'need duration and opacity'_. Duration and opacity are the first and second parameters of the `fadeTo` function, while `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` only provide duration, not finite control over the opacity (they will always animate towards 0 or 100 opacity). `fadeTo` may not be what you actually want, but it's what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

cant you just use , I think you can set the animations,duration and opacity as well.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ and http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to fade out the current image before fading in the next image, replace this line:

```
$("#img_div").css("background", "url('" + imagearray[count] + "')");
```

with:

```
var $imgDiv = $("#img_div");
$imgDiv.fadeOut("fast", function () {
    $imgDiv.css("background", "url('" + imagearray[count] + "')").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i need the function to be executed repeatedly thats why i used setInterval and clearInterval with count values

Comment: The substitution I proposed should be compatible with the rest of your code. It might be helpful to create a jsfiddle to help folks see and work with the problem.